# Missing AssumeRole Events for AssumedRole Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services

What are the reasons I might see `AssumedRole` identities whose access key ids don't have corresponding `AssumeRole` events in CloudTrail?

For example, I have an event with `userIdentity.accessKeyId = ASIAIVOTP66PNEXAMPLE`, but I can't find an `AssumeRole` event (or `AssumeRoleWithSAML` or `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`) with `responseElements.credentials.accessKeyId = ASIAIVOTP66PNEXAMPLE`